# How can I delete GET url parameter after creating array in django?

Tags: python, arrays, json, django

I am working django and I want to fetch GET requests from url and want to delete couple of parameter and than save rest of in database as list.

For example, requested url is

```
localhost/test?a=A&b=B&c=C&d=D&e=E
```

I know how to get GET parameters in json format by simply doing

```
json.dumps(reqest.GET)
```

and when I print it out in template HttpResponse, I get

```
{"a":"A", "b":"B", "c":"C", "d":"D", "e":"E"}
```

what I want to do is I want to remove couple elements from it and create json. I want to remove by key "a" and "d". So my json should look like,

```
{"b":"B", "c":"C", "e":"E"}
```

Can anyone tell me how can I do it? I tried to look for `list`, `json` to `list` etc and remove(), del `element` etc method. Each time I was getting errors so can anyone help me?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this,

```
a = json.loads(json.dumps(request.GET))

        del a['a']
        del a['d']

return HttpResponse(json.dumps(a), content_type="application/json")
```

Let me know if helps... :D ;)